# Is there is a simple way to tell if a graph is 3-connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Is there is a simple way to tell if a graph is 3-connected? In lecture, we use the definition that a graph is *k* connected iff it contains no proper separations of order < *k* $\therefore$ by this definition, a graph is 3-connected iff it contains no proper separations of order < 3. However using only this definition makes the process of determining if graphs are 3-connected rather arduous - and there is always the risk of missing a separation - so I was wondering if there were any other theorems/lemmas/corollaries/definitions which might make the process a bit quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Whitney's theorem is useful for vertex connectivity computations:
A graph $G$ is $k$-connected if and
only if for every pair of distinct vertices $a$, $b$ of $G$ there is a family of
$k$ disjoint $a$, $b$-paths in $G$.

See Theorem 3.3.5. (Global Version of Menger's Theorem)  in Reinhard Diestel's book Graph Theory.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent description of a number of algorithms is given [here.](https://www.quora.com/What-algorithm-decides-if-a-connected-graph-is-3-connected) All of these are far more efficient than Whitney's algorithm.